# Prove that $\mathbf{R^{n}}=U\oplus V$

Tags: linear-algebra

Define $U=\{(x_1,...,x_n)\in \mathbf{R^{n}}:x_1+\dots+x_n=0\}$ and $V=\{(x_1,...,x_n)\in \mathbf{R^{n}}:x_1=x_2=\dots=x_n\}$. I am demanded to prove  $\mathbf{R^{n}}=U\oplus V$.

The proof on $U\cap V=\{0\}$ is obvious. The core is to prove that $\mathbf{R^n}=U+V$.

My solution is to write $(x_1,\dots,x_n)=\Big(\frac{(n-1)x_1-x_2-\dots -x_n}{n},\frac{(n-1)x_2-x_1-\dots -x_n}{n},\dots,\frac{(n-1)x_n-x_1-\dots-x_{n-1}}{n}\Big)+\Big(\frac{x_1+\dots+x_n}{n},\dots,\frac{x_1+\dots+x_n}{n}\Big)$

Is my idea ok?

Comment: Please add some explanation about why *you* think your explanation is OK.

Comment: Your idea will be ok when you have verified that when you write your element as this summation the left is part of $U$ and the right is part of $V$. Additionally since you are showing set equality you need to prove $\mathbb{R}^n \subseteq U + V$ and $U + V \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$, so you should mention why one direction is clear.

Comment: $U$ and $V$ are orthogonal (w/r/t the standard dot product); $\dim U=n-1$ and $\dim V=1$. so $V$ is the orthogonal complement of $U$. they have to form a direct sum of $\mathbb{R}^n$